# Android Programming: How to maintain image size on different displays?

Tags: android, android-layout

e.g. I want a given Bitmap (100x200px) to always have the following size:

```
 height = 1/10 of the screens height
 length = 1/20 of the screens length,
```

no matter how large the screen is and what resolution it has. How can I do this without creating versions of my bitmap for each of the drawable folders (I've seen examples where all the pictures where only stored in the "drawable" folder, so there must be away without creating 4 instances of each picture used)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Get the width and height of the screen at runtime (Google it) and do the maths!

Comment: How are you displaying the image? in a ImageDrawable view? Drawing to a Canvas? If using an ImageDrawable you can just set the width/height of the ImageDrawable to whatever you want and tell it to scale it's contents.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It's possible, but note that screens are all of different sizes. Your 100x200 px image might be squashed or stretched on different screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your bitmap into an ImageView and set the ScaleType of the ImageView to 'FIT_XY' and  it will scale your image to whatever size your ImageView is.  You can set the ImageView size to be relative to your screen size by getting the screen dimensions from the WindowManager

For example:-

```
int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

float newWidth = 0.05f * screenWidth; 
float newHeight = 0.10f * screenHeight;

imageview.setScaleType( ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY ); 
imageview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( (int)newWidth, (int)newHeight ));
```

Answer (score 0):

final int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

final int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

then use bitmapfactory to scale the image